# How to show a list of students: pairing entity references?

Tags: entities

I'm working on a drupal page for an academic department, and I've created content types for Faculty, Students and Alumni.  Both the Student and Alumni content types have a field for "Advisor", which is an entity reference to a Faculty member.  In the student and alumni display, the advisor field then links to the advisor's page.

Now, I'd like to have the advisor page show a list of all their students (current and former).  Is there a simple module that will do this?  I don't want to write my own module - if there isn't a relatively simple way to do it, I can just have an entity reference in the Faculty content type and do manual entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EVA: Entity Views Attachment](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva) can help you doing this task.

> "Eva" is short for "Entity Views Attachment;" it provides a Views
>   display plugin that allows the output of a View to be attached to the
>   content of any Drupal entity. The body of a node or comment, the
>   profile of a user account, or the listing page for a Taxonomy term are
>   all examples of entity content.

See this tutorial: https://www.torontowebsitedeveloper.com/drupal-video-tutorials/drupal-7-node-reference-tutorial

"[Entity Views Attach: Use Views Almost Anywhere](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/entity-views-attach/)" contains a great tutorial about it.

Comment: This was perfect - exactly what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: @icurays1 you're welcome, good luck with your project ;-)